# ошибка nodemailer на сервере

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, deploy

(на localhost компе работал) почта и пароль правильные, отправляю на яндекс

```
const {usPocht} = req.query
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
            {
            host:'smtp.yandex.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user:process.env.EMAIL,
                pass:process.env.PASSWORD
            },
        })
        
    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL,
        to: usPocht,//куда
        subject:'Регистрации на сайте Макса',
        text: 'Код для подтверждения почты:  '+ ***
    }
    
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
    return res.status(200).json('Письмо отправлено')
```

Ответ:
{
"errno": -113,
"code": "ESOCKET",
"syscall": "connect",
"address": "77.88.21.158",
"port": 465,
"command": "CONN"
}

Comment: Распишите пожалуйста поподробней проблему. Я не очень понимаю по вашему вопросу, при какой ситуации у вас вылетает эта ошибка. Может код приведете, еще что-нибудь, чтобы было понятней?

Comment: посмотрите, добавил

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что на локалке у вас все нормально отправляется и т.д., а на каком-то хостинге, куда вы пытаетесь задеплоить свой проект, отправка писем не работает?

Comment: Да, правильно, может дело в сервере?

Comment: Уверен в этом на 99%, наверняка хостинг не позволяет подключаться к SMTP-серверам. Попробуйте другой.

Comment: спасибо, я так и думал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"хостинг не позволяет подключаться к SMTP-серверам"